# CurrentUser in .Net Core Microservice CQRS

Tags: c#, cqrs

namespace LED.OM.Core.Base

{
public abstract class BaseContext : DbContext
{
public BaseContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
{ }

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        UpdateAuditEntities();
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    public override int SaveChanges(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
    {
        UpdateAuditEntities();
        return base.SaveChanges(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess);
    }

    public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        UpdateAuditEntities();
        return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    private void UpdateAuditEntities()
    { 
        var CurrentUser = Thread.CurrentPrincipal?.Identity?.Name ?? "";
        var modifiedEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(x => x.Entity is Entity &&
                        (x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified || x.State == EntityState.Deleted));



        foreach (var entry in modifiedEntries)
        {

            var entity = (Entity)entry.Entity;
            var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

            if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                entity.CreatedDate = now;
                entity.CreatedBy = CurrentUser;
            }
            else if (entry.State == EntityState.Deleted && entry.Entity is not IHardDelete)
            { 
                // Varlığı değiştirilmedi olarak ayarlıyoruz.
                // (tüm varlığı Değiştirildi olarak işaretlersek, her alan güncelleme olarak Db'ye gönderilir)
                entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;

                // Yalnızca IsDeleted alanını güncelleyin - yalnızca bu Db'ye gönderilir
                entity.IsDelete = true;  
            }
            else
            {
                base.Entry(entity).Property(x => x.CreatedBy).IsModified = false;
                base.Entry(entity).Property(x => x.CreatedDate).IsModified = false;
            }

            entity.UpdatedDate = now;
            entity.UpdatedBy = CurrentUser;
        }
    }


}
```

}

[user.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K15fy.png)

[entity.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jtz7.png)

I am working with microservice. The entity is the common field in my entire table. I want to fill in the fields created and updated by those who want to log in. But I couldn't find how to fill this user info in BaseContext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not about microservices or CQRS. The problem is about Entity Framework Core. So you need to detect the modified entities in `UpdateAuditEntities()` method then you can fill the `UpdatedDate` and
`UpdatedBy` properties.

Also, this method already fills the `CreatedDate` and `CreatedBy` properties in creating `(EntityState.Added)` operations.

You can get an exception when casting entry.Entity to LED.OM.Core.Base.Entities.Entity. You should use this code for retrieving modified entries:  `var modifiedEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries<LED.OM.Core.Base.Entities.Entity>()...`

You should handle the updated entities `(EntityState.Modified)` like below:

```
private void UpdateAuditEntities()
    { 
        var CurrentUser = Thread.CurrentPrincipal?.Identity?.Name ?? "";
        var modifiedEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries<LED.OM.Core.Base.Entities.Entity>()
            .Where(x => x.Entity is Entity &&
                        (x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified || x.State == EntityState.Deleted));



        foreach (var entry in modifiedEntries)
        {

            var entity = (Entity)entry.Entity;
            var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

            if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                entity.CreatedDate = now;
                entity.CreatedBy = CurrentUser;
            }
            else if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
            {
                entity.UpdatedDate = now;
                entity.UpdatedBy = CurrentUser;
            }
            else if (entry.State == EntityState.Deleted && entry.Entity is not IHardDelete)
            { 
                // Varlığı değiştirilmedi olarak ayarlıyoruz.
                // (tüm varlığı Değiştirildi olarak işaretlersek, her alan güncelleme olarak Db'ye gönderilir)
                entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;

                // Yalnızca IsDeleted alanını güncelleyin - yalnızca bu Db'ye gönderilir
                entity.IsDelete = true;  
            }
            else
            {
                base.Entry(entity).Property(x => x.CreatedBy).IsModified = false;
                base.Entry(entity).Property(x => x.CreatedDate).IsModified = false;
            }

            entity.UpdatedDate = now;
            entity.UpdatedBy = CurrentUser;
        }
    }
```